# Re-naming files based on .csv file. Cycling through dictionary as guide

Tags: python, loops, csv, dictionary

I wrote a script that reads in a two column .csv file, turns it into a dictionary, which is then used as guide to renaming files in a directory.  If a file matches a key in the guide dictionary it renames it to the value.  The problem is that it only renames one file then stops; it does not loop through my guide dictionary.  It renames one file then stops.  New to Python and stackoverflow, so any feedback is welcome.

The directory is just a list of files

```
Barcode85.fq
Barcode73.fq
Barcode61.fq
Barcode86.fq
```

The .csv file is structured like this, where the first column is the new file name I want and the secodn "Barcode" are the filenames now:

```
wtcother1.3.4.fq, Barcode85.fq
wtcother2.fq, Barcode73.fq
wtcother6.fq, Barcode61.fq
wtcother6.fq, Barcode86.fq
ect.
```

The dictionary created looks like this:

```
['wtcother1.3.4.fq', 'Barcode85.fq']
['wtcother2.fq', 'Barcode73.fq']
['wtcother6.fq', 'Barcode61.fq']
['wtcmbr1.4.6.fq', 'Barcode86.fq']
ect.
```

The script is below:

```
import os
import csv

# make an empty dictionary which will hold the keys
keys = {}

#open file
with open('lane1Key.csv','rU') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar='"')
# build a dictionary with the associated ids
        for rowDict in reader:
              keys[ rowDict[0] ] = rowDict[1]
              print rowDict
# renaming
for fileName in os.listdir('.'):
    if fileName in rowDict:
        os.rename(fileName, rowDict[0])
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to walk through all files, just the ones in your dictionary:

```
for k in keys:
    os.rename(k, keys[k])
```

please note that you might have mixed up the first and the second column

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
# renaming
for fileName in ( os.listdir('.') & keys.keys() ):
    os.rename(fileName, keys[fileName])
```

This will iterate on the intersection of found files and those defined in the csv.

And if you can't change the order of columns in the csv-file, you need to adapt:

```
# build a dictionary with the associated ids
        for rowDict in reader:
              keys[ rowDict[1] ] = rowDict[0]
```